# Ways to determine a group of units in RTS

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining

Looking for an algorithm that can be used to determine groups of units that move together as a squad in a real time strategy game like StarCraft. The direction that I am currently look at is a clustering algorithm but having a hard time finding which one would work best since units are moving as a group not just standing still. Any help would be great.

Comment: What format is your data in? Any particular reason why you think a clustering algorithm on a snapshot of the positions would not be sufficient?

Comment: In real time, or looking at the history (so do you have space-time available, or only space)?

Comment: Well at first I will be look at replays which have both space and time but will in the future look at real time as well.

Answer (score 3):

K-means is not the best choice, as it requires you to specify the number of clusters you expect to find. Some might contain single objects then.

I recommend adapting DBSCAN. In particular, the generalized version GDBSCAN.

For this, you need to define what constitutes the neighborhood of a unit - say, any other unit within a range of `2` that is belonging to the same player and moving approximately in the same direction (up to a certain delta threshold in `x` and `y` velocity).

Next, you need to specify when you consider units to start forming an initial cluster, called "core point". Say that is a minimum of `3` units.

Then using DBSCAN is quite basic, and should give you good results. You need to fine-tune the parameters a bit. Things like this minimum size are clearly an input parameter, and depend on your use case. So is the neighborhood definition: you are looking for groups that move into the same direction, this information needs to be put into the algorithm somehow. With GDBSCAN this is trivial, by adjusting the neighborhood definition.

Comment: I will take a look, thanks. This sounds like what I am looking for.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that k-means is not a good choice b/c of the fixed number of clusters (k). You could take a RANSAC / random approach by applying k-means several times and choosing the best result, but DBSCAN seems to be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at a number of classification algorithms, like  [k-Nearest Neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) or [Support Vector Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)

Comment: Dunno, he seems to want clustering more then classification.

Comment: true, but he can classify a group as a cluster with those algorithms. A lot of classification algorithms will allow you to classify groups by clusters, or auto-detect clusters if they know how many to look for.

Answer (score 0):

[Kmeans](http://home.dei.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/kmeans.html) algorithm is quite simple and standard approach. You can check if it works: